# How to turn off bell sound in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got freshly installed Visual Studio Code on OSX with only [Emacs Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hiro-sun.vscode-emacs) extension.

When I'm trying to undo (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>) the bell sound occurs.

Any idea how to turn it off with this keybinding or for ever? I did not find any sound related settings in VSC configs.

Comment: I came here looking for this answer. I can only add that this setting for me did not change anything:`"terminal.integrated.enableBell": false`

Comment: for future, it worked, but only for a new terminal, so close all terminals and open it again without the annoying sound, also worth to take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/10575/turning-off-the-cmd-window-beep-sound)

Comment: I've posted the solution updating VS Code settings in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66505279/7761396](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66505279/7761396)

Answer (score 8):

For anyone stumbling on this question going crazy for an answer, the issue is related to this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44070

The bell sound actually occurs when you press `Ctrl+/` on *any* text input box (try it in Chrome address bar and Stickies).

You'll need to rebind the shortcut through `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

Go to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` (you'll need to `mkdir` and `touch` the file if it doesn't exist).

Add this:

```
{
    "^/" = "noop:";
}
```

Then restart vscode.

Comment: Thank you so much; it was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer from [mooncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465128/mooncoder) above... If you are on High Sierra or above (Mojave, Catalina), you'll need to use this as the contents of your `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file, as posted in  [this issue on gitHub.com](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/2419#issuecomment-344351507).

```
{
    "@^\UF701" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF702" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF703" = "noop:";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way that I've found is to disable all bell sounds in the operating system's control panel. I'm not sure where that's found for Mac, though.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd>
2. typeed settings, to open default visual code
   `settings.json`
3. added `"terminal.integrated.enableBell": false` (in
   the end of the file, before the closing `}`)
4. closed all integrated terminals opened
5. started a new terminal
6. hit the backspace and no sound =)

also, if you want to turn off the sound of the system (Windows), you can take a look  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/10575/turning-off-the-cmd-window-beep-sound), but I tried and even without the sound, the beep (another even more annoying) still happen inside visual code.

Comment: As of v1.56, the bell status now shows in the terminal list. See these release notes:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56

Comment: that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Just added `"audioCues.volume": 0` in my user settings.json. It works for me \o/

Comment: This worked for me to mute audio cues from github copilot (every single suggestion produced a cue).

Answer (score -5):

For mac users, the alert sound can be muted system-wide from System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects. Lower the "alert volume" all the way.

Comment: This turns off sound for the system. Similarly strong answers would be to turn off the computer. Answers must be specific and relevant. The best solutions have minimal side effects.