# How to turn off (or on) sounds from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to know how to turn off  sounds coming from VS Code. I'm running VSCode on Windows 10. I did a search in the settings:

[image: VS Code Settings Search]

and nothing showed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes this sounds irritates me also.. while using earphone and coding. The sound comes from `github copilot` or from vscode itself inside. To remove the sound please do the following procedures as i mentioned below:

1. Open settings

[image]

2. Search for sound in search bar of setting

[image]

3. Now disable all the sounds you want to disable

Answer (score 70):

This is because you possibly have **accessibility Support** enabled, so you just have to disable it.

```json
...
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
...
```

Comment:  super, I was really frustrated, no solution worked. yes accessibility is the reason and I kept searching for bell sound settings  MacOS VS code menu > Preferences > search Accessibility Support and turn off

Comment: This worked for me on macOS: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2617#issuecomment-571447707

Comment: In my case it looks like it switched on when I was testing with OSX VoiceOver and accidentally focused VS Code.

Comment: @Ludder did you already solve it?

Comment: @wootsbot Yes I did, but I can't remember how...

Comment: When on "auto" it usually turns on when testing MacOS voice over. This response helped me easily find the setting I was looking for in VScode to turn it off

Comment: I understand that if the line is removed, that also solves the issue

Answer (score 52):

VS Code v1.87 update:

`Audio cues` is being replaced by `Accesibility Signals` in the settings.  So search in the Settings for `signals` and you will find many settings like:

```
Accesibility > Signals: Line has Breakpoint
```

See also [v1.87 Release Notes: Accessibility signals](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_87.md#accessibility-signals):

> ##### Accessibility signals
>
> Accessibility signals encompass both sounds, formerly called audio
> cues, and announcements, formerly called alerts.
>
> The commands Help: List Signal Sounds and Help: List Signal
> Announcements allow users to view the available signals and configure
> them. Migration to this new configuration happens automatically.
>
> Before:
>
> ```json
> "audioCues.clear": "on | auto | off"
> "accessibility.alert.clear": true | false
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```json
> "accessibility.signals.clear": {
>     "sound": "auto | on | off",
>     "announcement" (optional): "auto | off" 
> }
> ```

As it mentions above, your settings should be migrated aiutomatically from `Audio Cues` to this new `Accessibility > Signals` terminology.

---

---

Prior to vscode v1.87:

Looks like there will be a new setting in vscode v1.76 for

```
Audio Cues: Terminal Command Failed
"Plays a sound when a terminal command fails (non-zero exit code)."
```

see [add audio cue for when a terminal command fails](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/56ba527736cc5c2ccc5073464923990840ed1049)

---

The previous audio cue setting: `Audio Cues: Enabled` is being replaced by a series of more specific settings.

But as of v1.66 there is a volume control for all audio cues that you could set to `0` to turn off or increase if the default of `50` is too low in volume:

You can individually enable/disable these:

```
Audio Cues: Diff Line Detected
Audio Cues: Diff Line Inserted
Audio Cues: Diff Line Modified
Audio Cues: Line Has Breakpoint  
Audio Cues: Line Has Error  
Audio Cues: Line Has Folded Areas  
Audio Cues: Line Has Inline Suggestion  
Audio Cues: Line Has Warning  
Audio Cues: No Inlay Hints
Audio Cues: Notebook Cell Completed
Audio Cues: Notebook Cell Failed 
Audio Cues: On Debug Break  
Audio Cues: Task Completed
Audio Cues: Task Failed
Audio Cues: Terminal Command Failed  - in v1.76
Audio Cues: Terminal Quick Fix
```

The above are the available settings as of vscode v1.75.  You can see the current list via the command `Help: List Audio Cues` or by searching in your Settings for `Audio Cues`.

The default `auto` in the Settings means the sound is enabled *if* there is screen reader attached.  `On` will play the sound even if there is no screen reader attached,

---

See [v1.64 Release Notes: Audio Cues](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_audio-cues):

> Audio cues indicate if the current line has certain markers, such as
> errors, breakpoints, or folded text regions.
>
> They are played when the primary cursor changes its line or the first
> time a marker is added to the current line. Audio cues are enabled
> automatically when a screen reader is attached, but can also be turned
> on manually by setting [the specific setting' to `on`.

Comment: Audio Cues: Line Has Error
this one was killing me thx so much!

Answer (score 28):

**MacOS / MacBook => VS Code Preferences => Accessibility Support => Off**

** I was using VIM extension and it was triggering bell sound each time I pass over a line with some error shown by linter.

[image: MacBook VS Code]

Answer (score 10):

Not an elegant solution, but works:

- Look towards the notification area which is typically located in the bottom-right corner of a Windows Desktop environment.
- Right-click the icon that looks like a Speaker, and select 'Open Volume Mixer' from the list of choices.

OR

- Press the 'Windows Key' or open the Start menu, and then type in 'audio devices' and select 'Manage audio devices' from the results, and hit enter.

THEN

- Scroll to the Application representing MS Visual Studio Code and hit the Mute button - voila!

Comment: Thanks. I just wish it didn't require such a brute force method.

Comment: Least it's a quick fix until someone else finds a more elegant solution!

Comment: if you cannot find VS code there, you will see system sounds. When you disable those, its off as well

Comment: I don't understand why this is the top answer on Google.  It doesn't really provide good instructions on turning off the sounds.  Spent 10 minutes trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: MSCode doesn't appear in Open Volume Mixer. Any idea? I'm on Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: Where the heck is the audio icon, system tray and the Open Volume mixer? Downvoting unless more explanation is provided. This could be a great awnser.

Comment: @MoteZart I've edited the post to make things about as clear as they can be for this basic brute of a solution.

Comment: @UnderBlue592 make sure the application is open and running in Windows Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc --> Processes tab). The most relevant-seeming solution I could find was [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7/applications-missing-from-volume-mixer/b64bce0f-9fac-456f-a5cd-f77a59cdc6f8).

Answer (score 10):

The solution is simple. You just have to adjust the audio volume number to "0" by entering the Visual Studio Code settings. I left the steps of the tutorial:

[image: show]

Comment: This is not completely reliable.  I have 1.75.1, `audioCues.volume: 0`, and it still beeps a lot.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this is going to help anyone but I'll add it anyway.

MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THE accessibility settings turned off.

There are some truly horrible things that can happen when you have them turned on. the bell will go crazy with sounds every time you move around.

```
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off", // Very F@#@ing IMPORTANT
```

Answer (score 6):

**Windows Only**

**TL;DR** Disable them system wide in Control Panel

I wanted to disable sound when discarding changes in VScode. It should work for all sounds tho since it's system wide.

From Windows Search Bar (next to Start): **Control Panel -> Sound -> Sounds**

In the drop down of sounds there are a number that play the same sound. You can test them first then set the ones U want to none. I disabled personally **Asterisks, Close Program, Default Beep, & Exclamation** to stop the sound.

This isn't a great solution since it disables the sounds via Windows system wide and not just in VScode, so be warned. These instructions are for Windows 10.[image]

Comment: Thank god I'm not the only one that hates this sound. Visual Studio Beep sound comes from the Default Beep when you undo changes in a file

Answer (score 2):

I got a cute solution, I hope it will work for you.
[image]

Make sure *Accessibility Support* is turned off

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. Ctrl + P
2. Type: Audio
3. Select "List Audio Cues"
4. Error on line (press on the kug wheel)
5. On Audio Cues: Line Has Error: Select Off

Answer (score 2):

In my case, simply turning off the screen reader feature stops the sound.
The condition here is that the audio cues settings must be set to default (most settings are on 'auto' or 'off').
[screen reader setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaZ5R.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to restart your terminals to make the following setting change to apply.

### JSON settings version

Add/update the following line :
"terminal.integrated.enableBell": false

### GUI version

1. Open the user settings by either :

   - In the terminal panel, clicking the dropdown terminals list *(in the upper-right corner)* then "Configure Terminal Settings"
   - Or opening the Command Palette (ctrl+shift+P)

     - "Preferences: Open User Settings"
     - In the Search input, enter "@feature:terminal"
2. Scroll down to "Terminal> Integrated: Enable Bell" and uncheck it

Answer (score 1):

For Mac. Go to: `System preferences` > search for `Keyboard` > and uncheck `Show accessibility controls` [image]

Comment: This was the fix for me. - and may be the fix for other users as well. I was sharing screen with someone via zoom, and had allowed them to control my system - they are on a mac, and I am on Windows - so their key commands were different. They accidentally turned accessibility controls on

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code, Enter Show all Commands key - Ctrl + Shift + P

Now Type Open Accessibility Setting in Prefereneces.
Now choose accesibility support to off
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDfVM.png)

Answer (score 1):

fortunately setting audio cue sound volume to 0 (search `audio` in `edit > preferences`) seems to fix this... albeit every once in a while the sound effects are cute.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Answer (score 0):

go vscode settings
and type
**Audio Cues**
[Click to view an image of my settings in this format] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdFeB.jpg)

select
**Audio Cues: of**,
then it's working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when moving Javscript files between directories.

[Although there was a feature request to disable system beep sound](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122124), it wasn't accepted.

You can either:

1. [change the dialog style to "custom"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122124#issuecomment-826300551)
2. disable windows beep sound altogether

On Windows, you can disable windows beep sound by opening Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Change system sounds, and setting both "Asterisk" and "Default Beep" to None.

"Asterisk" is used when moving files, and "Default Beep" is used for when updating imports.

[image: Sound: Windows Asterisk]
[image: Sound: Windows Default Beep]

Answer (score 0):

VS Code was beeping for me when saving files. I tried other answers here—setting volume to 0, turning off accessibility, etc.—and the only thing that fixed it for me was changing this setting:

`Accessibility > Signals: Save` changed from `userGesture` to `never`.

It beeped once when I pressed OK (as it saved this setting) and then never again. Sweet silence.

[image: Change the setting for the item "sound" from userGesture to never.]

This was for VS Code v1.87.2 on macOS

Answer (score -1):

If using mac, go to code -> settings -> settings -> search sound in search bar -> and disable all audio features.