# Adding audible alert for breakpoints in VS Code 1.52.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm aware of the following question and answers:

[Visual Studio: How to trigger an alarm when a breakpoint is hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80564/visual-studio-how-to-trigger-an-alarm-when-a-breakpoint-is-hit)

However, none of the solutions seem to work for me. I'm on Windows 10, with Visual Studio Code 1.52.1. When I go to the Windows sound settings, there is no Visual Studio section, so I can't set it there. The "ding" extension is no longer supported. The macro option also does not seem possible in my version of VS.

Does anyone know of any alternative solutions? I'm running code that takes sometimes 30+ minutes, so I would really benefit from an audible alert so I can immediately get back to work when it completes.

Answer (score 2):

As of vscode v1.87 the new audio cue alert for breakpoints will be these settings:

```
Accesibility > Signals: Line has Breakpoint
Accesibility > Signals: On Debug Break
```

see more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988028/836330

---

---

In the Insiders Build v1.65 there a few new individual settings controlling audio and it appears that the general `Audio Cues: Enabled` has been removed in favor of the more specific settings.

```
audioCues.onDebugBreak: Plays a sound when the debugger stopped on a breakpoint.  

audioCues.lineHasBreakpoint:  "Plays a sound when the active line has a breakpoint." 

audioCues.lineHasInlineSuggestion: "Plays a sound when the active line has an inline suggestion."  


audioCues.lineHasError: "Plays a sound when the active line has an error."  

audioCues.lineHasFoldedArea: "Plays a sound when the active line has a folded area that can be unfolded."

audioCues.lineHasWarning: "Plays a sound when the active line has a warning."  (off by default)
```

And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988028/836330 for how to list, hear and modify these settings using the

`Help: List Audio Cues` command from the Command Palette.

---

This is in the Stable Build v1.64 now.

Setting: `Audio Cues: Enabled`

`auto` : default -  `Enable audio cues when a screen reader is attached`
`on` : `Enable audio cues`
`off` : `Disable audio cues`

This works for breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested the feature on GitHub a while ago and they actually implemented it in vs code insiders January build.

[My github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135908)

[VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)