# Annoying Sound with GitHub Copilot When making in-line suggetions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

**Problem Statement**

For the last couple of days, I have been noticing that GitHub Copilot has been making a sound each time it makes a code snippet suggestion. At first, I thought there was something wrong with my computer and was worried that maybe one of the keys on the keyboard had jammed. It took me two days to figure it out that the sound was actually coming from GitHub Copilot.

The other problem is that I had checked the extension's settings and found nothing to do with disabling the sound that it has been producing, and there was no update for the plugin to any later version.

**Request**

How do I make this sound go away, because it has been actually annoying me each and every time a code suggestion has been made?

Comment: Does disabling the setting `Audio Cues: Line has Inline Suggestion` make any difference?  You could also try setting the `Audio Cues: Volume` to 0 to see if it helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggested you disable the fairly new setting

```
Audio Cues: Line has Inline Suggestion
```

As of **vscode 1.87** this will be:

```
Accesibility > Signals: Line has Inline Suggestion
```

If that hadn't worked there is a setting that would effectively disable all audio cues:

```
Audio Cues: Volume   // set to 0
```

and as of vscode v1.87:

```
Accesibilty > Signals > Sounds: Volume
```

Comment: You can place this value by going to:
Extensions > GitHub Copilot> (click the gear) Extension Settings > follow "Edit in settings.json"

Then add:

`"audioCues.volume": 0`

to the json file.

Comment: @mark your answer is confusing. Where am I suppose to type this? Please spell out step by step what the solution is to save everyone time.

Comment: This is not good enough, I want to completely mute vscode without muting my computer.

Comment: I have set "accessibility.signals.sounds.volume": 0 already, but I still get the damn sound!

Comment: Ok. by adding this line besides the "accesibility,signals.sounds.volume": 0 solved the problem: "accessibility.signals.lineHasInlineSuggestion": {
        "sound": "off"
    }

Answer (score 3):

I encountered an issue with unexpected audio feedback in Visual Studio Code, which seemed to be triggered by a change in the accessibility settings. Initially, my VS Code user settings had the `editor.accessibilitySupport` set to auto. This setting controls whether the UI optimizes for screen readers:

```
// Controls if the UI should run in a mode where it is optimized for screen readers.
//  - auto: Use platform APIs to detect when a Screen Reader is attached.
//  - on: Optimize for usage with a Screen Reader.
//  - off: Assume a screen reader is not attached.
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "auto",
```

The issue began when I opened an on-screen keyboard, and VS Code prompted me to confirm if I was using a Screen Reader. By mistakenly responding 'Yes' to this prompt, I activated the Screen Reader mode, which led to unexpected sound feedback from the editor.

To resolve this, I changed the `editor.accessibilitySupport` setting to off. This action successfully stopped the sounds. However, I noticed there isn't a straightforward method to toggle the Screen Reader Accessibility Mode directly within the UI.

For anyone experiencing similar issues with sound feedback after an accidental change in screen reader settings, modifying the `editor.accessibilitySupport` to off in the user settings should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the premises of the question is off. The sound doesn't come from the GitHub Copilot extension per-se. **The setting that controls this is `audioCues.lineHasInlineSuggestion`, which you can set to `0`** in [your settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). It's a builtin VS Code setting, which makes sense since inline suggestions is a general VS Code feature (that extensions can implement using [`InlineCompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlineCompletionItemProvider)), so it's not limited to the inline suggestions contributed by the GitHub Copilot extension. You'd get the same thing if you set up inline suggestions for regular code, or you're using another extension that uses the inline completion API, such as TabNine (IIRC).

Other related settings include (but are not limited to): `audioCues.volume`, (and, if you are using the GitHub Copilot Chat extension or other extension which uses the chat part of the VS Code extension API) `audioCues.chatRequestSent`, `audioCues.chatResponsePending`, `audioCues.chatResponseReceived`.

The audio cues might start playing if you enabled screen reader / accessibility mode (see also [What does VS Code do with my answer to "Are you using a screen reader to operate VS Code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75737471/11107541)).

Note that in VS Code 1.87, the schema for audio cues and accessibility alerts are merged into "signals" settings (see issue ticket [#202018](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202018)).

Comment: This is not good enough, I want to completely mute vscode without muting my computer.

Comment: @CharlieParker what specifically about setting the `audioCues.volume` setting (which is already mentioned in this answer post) to zero isn't working for you? see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54173462/11107541 where the top answer says to do the same thing. And by the way, what you're looking for is not even what this Q&A page is about, so your comment about this "not being good enough" doesn't make sense.

Comment: This did fix the issue for me. Also, who in the world thought that `on` was a good default for this setting?

Answer (score 0):

To mute the suggestion sounds. Follow these simple steps:

1. Click on the Extensions button on your Visual Studio code console.
2. Right-click on the settings icon of the Github Copilot Extension.
3. click on the "Extension Settings" option in the dropdown menu.
4. There will be a search bar on top with "@ext:GitHub.copilot" written in it. In there search for "Volume".
5. A dialog box of "Audio Cues: Volume" will appear which will have a range of input from 0-100.
6. To mute the suggestion sounds, change the value of that input to "0" and this should mute it.

This worked for me.

Comment: my answer already covers this.