How to deactivate Accessible View on VS code
I have an accessible view that is displayed every single time I build my C++ code with CMAKE. This crashes my system and makes it laggy I always have to restart visual studio code.
I would like to disable it but I don't know how to. Please assist.
I have gone to preferences: open accessibility settings and unchecked everything related to accessibility. This persists

what about https://stackoverflow.com/q/75737471/11107541 ?
